# Creating bootable windows image from a logical volume

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtualbox, lvm

Recently I have taken raw image (using dd) of a logical drive of my laptop running windows 10. I would like to convert this  into a bootable Virtual Disk so that live analysis of OS can be performed. Can anyone help/suggest how to covert logical RAW image to bootable Virtual disk. I tried  "VBoxMange convertfromraw" to covert RAW image to VDI, but could not succeed as the image is not having any boot information.

When I tried fdisk -l on image, i could not see any partition data, though when connectd to loop, i could see all folders and files.

Comment: Sounds like it's a partition image rather than a disk image - just a single filesystem. That's why you can mount and browse it and there are no partitions.

Comment: Yes. can i fuse partition into it?

Answer (score 0):

You've imaged just a partition (eg. `/dev/sda1`), not an entire disk (`/dev/sda`). It's less than ideal, because you now have to reconstruct the partition table and other partitions that you may need to get the OS running.

Ideally, you should've used a cloning software such as Clonezilla. It would have numerous advantages:

- It lets you select which partitions to clone
- Partition table is preserved too
- It automatically restores boot records and configuration
- It doesn't copy unused empty space, producing a smaller image faster

The disadvantage is that [mounting a Clonezilla image is difficult](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103181/53467).

---

You haven't provided any information about your previous setup that would be necessary to type out a recovery plan:

- MBR or GPT?
- BIOS boot or UEFI boot?
- GRUB, systemd-boot, EFI stub or something else?
- Separate `/boot`? Any other mount points?

In this case the best advice I can give is:

1. Create a new VM with a disk of identical size or larger.
2. Clean install the same OS with exactly the same partitioning you've used previously.
3. Shutdown the VM and attach the old image as a 2nd disk (converted from raw with the method you've used).
4. Copy the filesystem from the old disk to the new OS partition, overwriting the clean installation you've made. You can use dd:

   ```
    dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda1 bs=1M status=progress
   ```

   or Partclone (more efficient and won't grow the image unnecessarily):

   ```
    partclone.ext4 -b -s /dev/sdb -o /dev/sda1
   ```

You may also have to update `/etc/fstab` entries, update GRUB configuration, rebuild the initramfs image and do a few other things, but I can't tell without extra information.